# Obscure typing bug with vue and input slider

Tags: typescript, vue.js

The type of a value is being changed by using an input slider, and not being caught by typescript.

app.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import adjuster from './Comp.vue'

const images = ref(20)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ images }}</h1>
  <adjuster v-model = images> </adjuster>
  <h1>{{ images+5 }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ images*5 }}</h1>
</template>
```

component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const numberOfImages = defineModel();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  <label for="numImagesSlider">No. of images in set:&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="range"  style="width:175px;" id="numImagesSlider"
    v-model="numberOfImages"
    :min="12" max="55" step="1"
    >
    <label>&nbsp;{{ numberOfImages }}</label>
  </div>
</template>
```

[Working demo here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

The value sent to the slider is a number; the value returned is a string. Javascript is correctly converting it back to a number when I multiply it , but not when I add to it.
Having found this effect (which took a while because my values were part of a complex object and not a simple variable), I now know that I have to use something like

```
images = Number(images)
```

when the form containing the slider is submitted.

So, my question is: why hasn't typescript parser been able to flag a problem here? It's just the sort of Javascript error that I though typescript was supposed to avoid!

The demo above is the simplest I could show. [This demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) is more like the effect I was actually seeing, getting a much laregr random number than I wanted!

Comment: While I haven't followed the Vue landscape closely enough in the recent years to answer your question about TS tooling, in general the values you get out of native inputs are always strings, if you want them to be something else you need to handle that separately. In Vue, [modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#number) can be used for that purpose.

Comment: typing defineModel, e.g. `defineModel<number>()` will generate warnings